# compiling bash shell script in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-android

```
bash ${workspace_loc: /com.todperkings.moleitx.moleitx}/build_native.sh NDK_DEBUG=1 V=1
```

it is a cocos-2dx project in android on windows 7. how to run this build command on eclipse. Cygwin is installed.

Building and Monetizing Game Apps for Android
i am trying to follow this tutorial 
the error is that tutorial operating system is mac and i am running windows 7

Comment: bit of problem occur .... use mac ....

Comment: @user2078315 there would be some way

Comment: when i started I did try all the way for window ....everything is right but some files are missing when u create the new project ...

Comment: way is .. follow the coocs2d-x official site or raywendrich website ....